# Do-while loop to erase cells with certain values in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete all cells that have a '+' and a '-' in D column. I've tried the following macro, which I thought would work, but nothing happens.

```
 Sub doWhile4()

'Replace blank spaces with underscores in a Range of Cells, using VBA loops; or 'Remove     
 blank spaces in a Range of Cells, using VBA loops.

 Dim iCell As Range
 Dim textString As String
 Dim n As Integer

'iCell is a Cell in the specified Range which contains the textString
'textString is the text in a Cell in which blank spaces are to be replaced with
'underscores. n is the position of blank space(s) occurring in a textString

 For Each iCell In ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D34")
     textString = iCell
     n = InStr(textString, "+")

    'The VBA InStr function returns the position of the first occurrence of a string within
    'another string. Using this to determine the position of the first blank space in the 
    'textString.

     Do While n > 0
         textString = Left(textString, n - 1) & Right(textString, Len(textString) - n)

        'This line of code is to remove all blank spaces in the   
        'textString

         n = InStr(textString, "+")
     Loop
     iCell = textString
 Next

 End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if it's just a typo here or if it's in your actual code but you have `iCell = textStrig` instead of `iCell = textString`. Make sure you have `Option Explicit` at the top of the module to catch these kind of errors

Comment: I only made that mistake here, I have it right in my module, so that's not the problem. I will try that 'Option Explicit'.

Comment: OK - I've fixed that typo in your question

Comment: So you want to delete the entire cell containing '+' or '-'? Your comments within the code are somewhat misleading.

Comment: Both, I forgot to add that to the comment.Still, if only I could get to work for one of them, it would be nice.

Comment: your code not structured in a way that facilitates "deleting" but I assume you want to clear out the value in the cells if either "+" or "-" exists in the `cell.value`

Comment: I gave you can alternative answer using SpecialCells to clear all the cells in one step with no loop... but you need to clarify, do you want to clear cells that have just **+** or **-** or do you want to clear cells that contain those characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to clear out the values if cell contains either + or -

```
Option Explicit

Sub doWhile4()

'Replace blank spaces with underscores in a Range of Cells, using VBA loops; or
'Remove blank spaces in a Range of Cells, using VBA loops.

 Dim iCell As Range
 Dim textString As String
 Dim n As Integer
 Dim hasPlus As Boolean
 Dim hasMinus As Boolean

'iCell is a Cell in the specified Range which contains the textString
'textString is the text in a Cell in which blank spaces are to be replaced with
'underscores. n is the position of blank space(s) occurring in a textString

 For Each iCell In ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D34")
     textString = iCell
     'reset our boolean variables for each iteration
     hasPlus = False
     hasMinus = False
     If InStr(textString, "+") > 0 Then hasPlus = True
     If InStr(textString, "-") > 0 Then hasMinus = True

    'The VBA InStr function returns the position of the first occurrence of a string within
    'another string. Using this to determine the position of the first blank space in the
    'textString.

     If hasPlus Or hasMinus Then iCell.Value = vbNullString

 Next

 End Sub
```

Comment: @Philip there are many ways to skin a cat, obviously. I try to minimally tinker with OP's code, when possible. I would further refine mine though (the `hasplus` and `hasMinus` variables aren't really necessary... What "one line of code" are you talking about? The 4 lines that you wrote which unnecessarily manipulate the worksheet by filling it with formulas before clearing the entire rows of data, with no regard for the rest of the worksheet structure/integrity? It works, but it's absolutely not how I would do it. Ever.

Comment: hmmm, of course yes it's 4 lines of code, and the OP would need to put that column of formulae in the right place...but thx for your views, you stick to your loops for possibly thousands of operations and I'll do the same job in 4 operations ...

Comment: exactly WHERE do I clear 'entire rows of data' ? My code, different and outside your experience it may be, only clears cells in one column

Comment: @Philip, sorry I misread your answer. As I mentioned above, I try to work within the framework provided by OP which in this case used a loop. I did change it from a `While` loop to `For` as a matter of preference.  In any case, it still seems you're unnecessarily manipulating the worksheet by filling column F with a bunch of formula -- your method works fine as long as you can safely rely on the assumption that it's OK to manipulate the worksheet. In my work, this is rarely true.

Comment: sorry for getting on my high horse... I took your comment the wromg way, you are quite correct, there are many ways to do it - I almost always try to avoid operations on worksheets in loops because I once got into a situation of a loop taking a very long time..and I like to be in the habit of using Excel formulae whenever I can too -Also, I can here point out that as developers, I believe we can decide if it's ok to add a hidden column 100 columns over to facilitate a task inside our code - the users will never know, but they might have a slightly faster process.

Comment: @Philip cheers. I probably took your first comment a bit too personally, too :)

Answer (score 0):

try the below.

Essentially it creates a formula in column F that searches for + or - within your column D and returns an NA# error if it finds one, then we use Excels SpecialCells function to return and clear all the cells that have that error...

```
Sub clearCells()
'
Dim sFormula As String
'
sFormula = "=IF(IF(OR(IF(ISERROR(FIND(""+"",A:A)),"""",IF(FIND(""+"",A:A)>0,1,0))=1,IF(ISERROR(FIND(""-"",A:A)),"""",IF(FIND(""-"",A:A)>0,1,0))=1),1,0)=1,NA(),"""")"

'
' put in formula to find the cells with the characters in them...
Range("F1:F" & Range("D1").End(xlDown).Row).Formula = sFormula
'
' now clear the cells returned by SpecialCells ...
Range("A1").Worksheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Offset(0, -2).Clear
'
' clean up the formula
Range("F1:F" & Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row).clear
'
End Sub
```

I hope that helps

Philip